# React component not re-rendering on state change using setState

Tags: react-native

I have a HomeScreen component which has button. I am trying to popup a modelview(Seperate component ie PopUpView) on the button click. In PopUpView i am sending its visibility as prop (isVisible).On the click of the button i am trying to change the state value popUpIsVisible from false to true. Hoping that this would re-render and popup my model view(Note this is working fine if i explicitly pass true). However with the state change it look like the render function is not being called and the popUp is not being displayed. Thanks for your help in advance

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button, TouchableHighlight, Alert, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import PopUpView from './src/PopUpView';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        popUpIsVisible: false,
      };
    }

  setPopUpIsVisible(isVisible){
    this.setState({popUpIsVisible: isVisible });
  }

  render() {
    this.setPopUpIsVisible = this.setPopUpIsVisible.bind(this);
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:"blue" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <PopUpView isVisible={this.state.popUpIsVisible}/>
          <Button onPress={() => {this.setPopUpIsVisible(true)}}  title="Open PopUp Screen"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

PopUpView.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Modal,StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import { TabView, TabBar,SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }} />
);
const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} />
);
const ThirdRoute = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} />
);


export default class PopUpView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          modalVisible:this.props.isVisible,
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            { key: 'first', title: 'HIGHLIGHTS' },
            { key: 'second', title: 'AMENITIES' },
            { key: 'third', title: 'FACILITIES' },
          ],
        };
    }
    setModalVisible(visible) {
      this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
    }

renderHeader = props => <TabBar
    {...props}
    indicatorStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
    tabStyle={styles.bubble}
    labelStyle={styles.noLabel}
/>;

  render() {
      return (
      <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.navBar}>
              <Text style={styles.navBarTitle}>Test</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
              <Icon style={styles.closeButton} name="close" size={35} color="grey" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <TabView
              navigationState={this.state}
              renderScene={SceneMap({
                first: FirstRoute,
                second: SecondRoute,
                third: ThirdRoute,
                })}
              onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
              initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
              renderTabBar={props =>
                      <TabBar
                          {...props}
                          style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                          indicatorStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
                          tabStyle={styles.bubble}
                          labelStyle={styles.label}
                      />
                  }
              />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    margin: 50,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "grey",
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  navBar:{
    height:70,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  navBarTitle:{
    fontSize: 25,
    fontFamily: 'Optima',
    paddingLeft:15,
  },
  closeButton:{
    paddingRight:12,
  },
  label: {
        color: 'black'
    }
})
```

Comment: can you share the PopUpView.js file

Comment: because after adding the binding line inside constructor it should work fine

Comment: If i use <PopUpView isVisible={true}/> instead of <PopUpView isVisible={this.state.popUpIsVisible}/>, the popUp is showing up. I don't think there is anything wrong with PopUpView.js

Comment: see this code, it's working fine https://snack.expo.io/r1NF7WY6N

Comment: thanks for the code Piyush. I have added PopUpView.js. Still not working for me

Comment: I would remove `modalVisible` from the state of PopUpView and use just `isVisible` prop to decide when to show the modal. Give it a try

Comment: But the Model show and close is again dependent on state. If i directly use prop i wont be able to close the Model

Comment: Did you debug and see the value in this.state.popUpIsVisible ?

Comment: Guruparan - Yes and its getting set.
this.setState({popUpIsVisible: isVisible }, function () {
             console.log("VISIBILITY IS "+this.state.popUpIsVisible);
        });

Comment: I still think having `modalVisible` is redundant. The accepted answer points this out. As a general rule of thumb try to minimize redundancy and have only one single source of truth, if possible.
A good read: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the state inside the PopUpView which does not change when you change the external prop. to fix this you should use the componentwillreceiveprops and update your state accordingly.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.props.isVisible!=nextProps.isVisible){
    this.setState({modalVisible:nextProps.isVisible})
  }
}
```

The better approach will be using the `this.props.isVisible` as the `visible` prop for the Model.
In this scenario you will have to pass a function as a prop to popupview which will set the popUpIsVisible to false.
Something like below

```
 <PopUpView isVisible={this.state.popUpIsVisible} 
            onDismiss={()=>{this.setState({popUpIsVisible:false})}}/>
```

You can call the onDismiss inside the child as

```
<Modal visible={this.props.isVisible}>
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => {
      this.props.onDismiss();
    }}>
 <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
</Modal>
```

The second approach is better as the visibility of the child is controlled by the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the code Guruparan. It working now. However i need to click twice on the button for the first time to open the pop up. For the subsequent clicks it works fine. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Only thing i can think of is the default values for the states better debug and see how that changes

Comment: There was a typo which was causing this issue. Now its working fine. Thanks Guruparan for your time and quick response. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add below line into constructor after state defining

```
this.setPopUpIsVisible = this.setPopUpIsVisible.bind(this);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried this but it still doesn't work